# What is the opposite of :hover (on mouse leave)?

Tags: css, hover

Is there any way to do the opposite of `:hover` **using only** CSS? As in: if `:hover` is `on Mouse Enter`, is there a CSS equivalent to `on Mouse Leave`?

Example:

I have a HTML menu using list items. When I hover one of the items, there is a CSS color animation from `#999` to `black`. How can I create the opposite effect when the mouse leaves the item area, with an animation from `black` to `#999`?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/SZqkb/)

(Have in mind that I do not wish to answer only this example, but the entire "opposite of `:hover`" issue.)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe there is a different alternative?

Comment: The opposite of `:hover` is quite simply `:not(:hover)`; however, `:hover` is *not* synonymous with `onmouseenter` nor is `:not(:hover)` the same as `onmouseleave`. CSS doesn't have any concept of DOM events.

Comment: When your mouse leaves the area, `:hover` ceases to be applied and returns to the previous style. So, the 'default' style is the equivalent of your 'mouse leave'.

Comment: @BoltClock can you explain further?

Comment: @Cthulhu: `:hover` simply means "an element that has a mouse pointer over it". It doesn't indicate if the mouse pointer transitioned from another element to this element. It just means that the mouse pointer is currently on the element.

Comment: @BoltClock would :not(:hover) actually do anything be triggered at all?

Comment: @Moin Zaman: Yep. As long as your mouse isn't over a certain element, then `:not(:hover)` will apply. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/rghBX

Comment: Nice! I can think of few interesting things to do with that...

Answer (score 135, accepted):

If I understand correctly you could do the same thing by moving your transitions to the link rather than the hover state:

```
ul li a {
    color:#999;       
    transition: color 0.5s linear; /* vendorless fallback */
    -o-transition: color 0.5s linear; /* opera */
    -ms-transition: color 0.5s linear; /* IE 10 */
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s linear; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s linear; /*safari and chrome */
}

ul li a:hover {
    color:black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/sELKu/3/

The definition of hover is:

> The :hover selector is used to select elements when you mouse over
>   them.

By that definition the opposite of hover is any point at which the mouse is **not** over it. Someone far smarter than me has done this article, setting different transitions on both states - http://css-tricks.com/different-transitions-for-hover-on-hover-off/

```
#thing {
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;

  /* HOVER OFF */
   -webkit-transition: padding 2s;
}

#thing:hover {
   padding: 20px;
   border-radius: 15px;

  /* HOVER ON */
   -webkit-transition: border-radius 2s;
}
```

Comment: "(Have in mind that I do not wish to answer only this example, but the entire "opposite of :hover" issue.)"

Comment: @Cthulhu - I've edited my answer now. That might help a bit more. I thought that was too obvious an answer.

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the right direction. I was having an animation discrepancy between browsers. Chrome was rendering everything smoother but I had a .1s different in transitions and Mozilla and IE were both displaying the error. I was able to fix it by matching up my transition numbers.

Comment: Ugh. The 'definition' of `:hover` you've quoted is from W3Schools, who are in no way an authoritative source. The actual spec can be found at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes, although it's not the most accessible explanation.

Answer (score 115):

The opposite is using `:not`

e.g.

`selection:not(:hover) { rules }`

Comment: HOW is this not the accepted answer? That exactly what the OP has asked!

Comment: This is something I wanted badly. <3

Comment: What a nice answer, I was blending the color with background image of div on hover but didn't get the animation on mouse leave. I used this answer to blend again white color to background image tricking CSS.

Comment: This is the correct answer!! thank you!!

Comment: Let this answer be known to everyone!!

Comment: This answer with [an empty keyframe](https://blog.timhagn.com/restart-css3-animations-on-hover-without-javascript/) allowed my `animation: YOUR_KEYFRAME 5.2s linear infinite running;` on the element `.ticker-tape:not(:hover) .ticker-tape-collection { animation: emptyanim_KEYFRAME; animation-play-state: paused; }` to be reset (without transition between animation keyframes).

Comment: @BrunoBrant "HOW is this not the accepted answer?" - Maybe because he's 9 years late?

Comment: Absolute legend!! Thank you very much

Comment: @MarinaDunst I was just expressing how this answer is great; of course that's the why.

Comment: AMAZING! This is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: This is so useful, thanks! I was doing some styling with scrollbar thumb when hover and mouse leave (`:not(:hover)` apparently) on scrollable area. I wanted the scrollbar thumb fade out with 1.5s delay when mouse left the scrollable area and this really helped me out!

Answer (score 41):

Just use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions) instead of animations.

```css
A {
    color: #999;
    transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
}

A:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SZqkb/66/)

Comment: Like I said on the example, my issue is not with the animation, but with the "on mouse leave" part.

Comment: Transition works both on mouse over and mouse leave. It's enough to specify styles for normal state and `:hover` state.

Comment: How do you stop the transition at the instant when the webpage loads?

Comment: @CloudWalker Not sure what you mean. Transition cannot be stopped, it rolls back when the selector does not match anymore.

Comment: For example, if you have a transition on text colour from black to white, then the instant the text loads, it changes from white to black(same duration as the transition duration). Not sure if this is an issue on my end.

Comment: @CloudWalker Are you talking about my live demo or about your own case? If the former, I cannot reproduce this: transition is not triggered on page load. If the latter, your page probably applies some transition-involving styles (e.g. via adding a class) on page load.

Answer (score 6):

Put your duration time in the non-hover selection:

```
li a {
  background-color: #111;
  transition:1s;
}

li a:hover {
  padding:19px;
}
```

Comment: In my case this helped. It would transition back to the default value.

Answer (score 5):

Just add a transition to the element you are messing with. Be aware that there could be some effects when the page loads. Like if you made a border radius change, you will see it when the dom loads.

```css
.element {
  width: 100px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
 
 .element:hover {
  width: 200px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No there is no explicit property for mouse leave in CSS.

You could use :hover on all the other elements except the item in question to achieve this effect. But Im not sure how practical that would be.

I think you have to look at a JS / jQuery solution.

Comment: JS is not needed in this case, and I would now discourage it, though a justification of performance.

Comment: It's not needed for the example above, but it appears to be the best solution for the whole "mouse leave" problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a transition and the name of the animation on the class inicial, in your case, ul li a, just add a "transition" property and that is all you need

```css
ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

ul li a {
    color: #999;
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-animation: item-hover-off 1s;
    -moz-animation: item-hover-off 1s;
    animation: item-hover-off 1s;
}

ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-animation: item-hover 1s;
    -moz-animation: item-hover 1s;
    animation: item-hover 1s;
}

@keyframes item-hover {
    from {
      color: #999;
      }
    to {
      color: black;
      }
}
    
@-moz-keyframes item-hover {
    from {
        color: #999;
      }
    to {
        color: black;
      }
}
    
@-webkit-keyframes item-hover {
    from {
        color: #999;
      }
    to {
        color: black;
      }
}

@keyframes item-hover-off {
    from {
      color: black;
      }
    to {
      color: #999;
      }
}
    
@-moz-keyframes item-hover-off {
    from {
        color: black;
      }
    to {
        color: #999;
      }
}
    
@-webkit-keyframes item-hover-off {
    from {
        color: black;
      }
    to {
        color: #999;
      }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>About</a></li>
    <li><a>Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of using `transition` is just specifying the **milliseconds** like so: `transition: 500ms;`

Try the following snippet

```css
div{
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  transition: 500ms;
}
div:hover{
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>HOVER ME</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3 transition

**Some good links:**

http://css-tricks.com/different-transitions-for-hover-on-hover-off/

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understanding-css3-transitions/

Answer (score 2):

This will add background color to the `.icon` when hovered and background fades when mouse pointer left the element..

```css
.icon {
   transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out; /* this is important */
}
.icon:hover {
   background-color: rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.9);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although answers here are sufficient, I really think [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp) example on this issue is very straightforward (it cleared up the confusion (for me) right away).

> Use the `:hover` selector to change the style of a button when you move
>   the mouse over it.
>
> **Tip:** Use the transition-duration property to determine the speed of
>   the "hover" effect:
>
> Example
>
> ```
> .button {
>     -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari & Chrome */
>     transition-duration: 0.4s;
> }
>
> .button:hover {
>     background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
>     color: white;
> }
> ```

In summary, for transitions where you want the "enter" and "exit" animations to be the same, you need to employ transitions on the main selector `.button` rather than the hover selector `.button:hover`. For transitions where you want the "enter" and "exit" animations to be different, you will need specify  different main selector and hover selector transitions.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood `:hover`; it says the mouse is over an item, rather than the mouse has just entered the item.

You could add animation to the selector without `:hover` to achieve the effect you want.

Transitions is a better option: http://jsfiddle.net/Cvx96/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't produce the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of `:hover` appears to be `:link`.

(edit: not technically an opposite because there are 4 selectors `:link`, `:visited`, `:hover` and `:active`. Five if you include `:focus`.)

For example when defining a rule `.button:hover{ text-decoration:none }` to remove the underline on a button, the underline shows up when you roll off the button in some browsers. I've fixed this with `.button:hover, .button:link{ text-decoration:none }`

This of course only works for elements that are actually links (have href attribute)

Comment: Your information is incorrect. `:link` just selects links, as simple as that. Look here the definition of `:link`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alink

Comment: @Strive55 Ahhh, thanks, that makes sense. The link you gave states that "In order to appropriately style links, you need to put the :link rule before the other ones, as defined by the LVHA-order: :link — :visited — :hover — :active." If I understand it correctly, that means that if none of the other selectors apply (:visited, :hover, or :active) then :link is the one that applies. Not technically an opposite, because there are 4, but it still works