# Drop down div with select box does not work IE9

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I have problem with IE9. I have drop down menu with select boxes and if I try to select value hover div will disappeared. I tried to figure out by some codes but I'm stuck. Here is my code. So If some will have any idea how to fix that IE bud I'll be so glad. THX

code: http://jsfiddle.net/fT7D3/13/

Comment: answer updated, now working fine on IE9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fT7D3/25/)

Try this code :

```
$('.left_content_tab_combobox').focus(function() {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown').addClass('dropdown_hover'); }).blur(function() {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown').removeClass('dropdown_hover');
});
```

Comment: Sorry I'm stackoverflow newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

Modified your html+css and used jQuery to hide&show the dropdown. This is probably not possible by using only the `:hover` pseudoselector, you can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995165/css-opposite-of-hover-on-mouse-leave).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.drop').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#menu .content').hide();
        $(this).next('.content').show();
    });
    $('.closex').click(function(){
        $(this.parentNode).hide();
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBPPw/1/) / [paste](http://pastebin.com/Ts9CkXGE)

Comment: THX for response but Ahmad Alfy figured out how to do that just only with hover.....