# Transition hover div css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I try to add a delay on a transition.

I have these rules :

```
#mydiv{
  z-index : 100;
  top : 50%;
  left : 50%; 
  -webkit-transition:width 1s, height 1s, background-color 1s ,-webkit-transform 1s, margin-left 1s;
  transition:width 1s, height 1s, background-color 1s, transform 1s, margin-left 1s;
}

#mydiv:hover{
  width : 700px;
  margin-left : -350px;
  text-align : left;
}
```

I know I can add "transition-delay" but I don't want a delay on hover but only when I quit the hover state.

I prefer to code it with css, not with JS ...

Any solution ?

Comment: You can't do that via CSS. Youse jQuery/JS. There's an event "onmouseleave", dont reinvent the wheel with CSS.

Comment: It's not to "reinvent the weel" I don't want to use JS for those kind of tricks. I think it's stupid to use JS for somethings that you can do in a better way in CSS, plus, better performances !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add transition-delay on #mydiv, then overwrite it on :hover.

```
#mydiv{
    z-index : 100;
    top : 50%;
    left : 50%; 
    -webkit-transition:width 1s, height 1s, background-color 1s ,-webkit-transform 1s, margin-left 1s;
    transition:width 1s, height 1s, background-color 1s, transform 1s, margin-left 1s;
    transition-delay: .5s;
}
#mydiv:hover{
    width : 700px;
    margin-left : -350px;
    text-align : left;
    transition-delay: 0;
}
```

Example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sx2s5/

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find this answer a bit useful:
[CSS: opposite of :hover (on mouse leave)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995165/css-opposite-of-hover-on-mouse-leave)
CSS doesn't have a command for "unhovering" but you could attach what you want on the a.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler way to do it without transition-delay: http://jsfiddle.net/v7BnQ/.

HTML:

```
<div id = "mydiv">Generic Division</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#mydiv{
    position: absolute;
    top : 50%;
    left : 50%; 
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}

#mydiv:hover{
    width : 700px;
    margin-left : -350px;
    text-align : left;
    transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this line on `#mydiv` : `transition: all 0.5s linear;`
You will be able to feel a little delay when you quit the hover state on a link.