# Reverse Animation of onHover

Tags: css, animation, transition, back

I am using CSS Animation for my Homepage. 
Since there is no opposite of onHover I 
have tried [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995165/css-opposite-of-hover-on-mouse-leave):

but it does not really work for me.

See that:

`fiddle`https://jsfiddle.net/mus8sdL0/`

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

HTML

```
<section class="half">
  <div id="containertop">
  <div class="titletextup">
    UP 
    <br>
    <div id="triangle-facing-top"></div>
  </div> 
  </div>
</section>

<section class="half">
  <div class="titletextdown">
    <div id="triangle-facing-bottom"></div>
    <br>
    DOWN 
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'corbertregular', arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    color:white;
}
header {
    height: 50px;
    background: gray;
}
main {
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    background: green;
}
.half {
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.half:first-child {

    border-bottom:10px;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-top:0px;
    border-bottom-color:white;
    border-style:solid;
}

#containertop {
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
}

.half:first-child > #containertop{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    transition: 2s all ease;
}

.half:first-child:hover > #containertop{
    top: -100%;
}

.half:last-child {
    background: green;
    border-top:10px;
    border-bottom:0px;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-top-color:white;
    border-style:solid;
}

.titletextup{
  text-align:center;
}

.titletextdown{
 text-align:center;
}

#triangle-facing-top {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 72px;
    border-right: 24px solid; border-bottom: 24px solid;
    width: 120px; height: 120px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    display: inline-block;
   -webkit-transform:rotate(-135deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(-135deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(-135deg);
   color: white;
}

#triangle-facing-bottom {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 72px;
    border-right: 24px solid; border-bottom: 24px solid;
    width: 120px; height: 120px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    display: inline-block;
   -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
   color:white;
}
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7grt5e51/)

---

For both bottom and top `animation` [Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqLsmdoh/)

Comment: Works fine for me! Thanks! But I can't see the part were it says: animate to top. You just set in the on hover part the new top position. Could you explain that, please?

Comment: This is obviously the right answer, but can you be so kind and give a bit more explanation on why and how this works. Lately i have been seeing more and more of these answers that start with *Try this...* . Even if this is the right answer, it will not help the OP to understand what is going on here. Thanks.

Comment: I've used `transition` instead of `animation`

Comment: [Check out this link for transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Hope this solved your question...

Comment: yes, it is. I had a following problem and I thought no one would read the threat anymore if it is solved. my plan was to check it solved again after some time... I'm sorry, i'll check it now again...

Comment: well, I would vote up if I could But Stackoverflow blocks me because I have not enough experience yet....