# How can I hover over a blank space on a site and make an image fade in and slowly fades out after my mouse leaves that spot?

Tags: css

I am able to make the image fade in but it immediately disappears when the cursor is off the image. I want it to slowly fade out. Here is an example of what I am wanting http://byvictoriageorge.studio/

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without code examples, but here is some theory.

You have a transition on your Image with opacity 0, and then it transitions to opacity 1 when hover.

You need to duplicate the same functionality, but vice versa. So what you can do it use the `ease-in-out;` setting on the `transision` css property.

So the full transition CSS would be soemthing like: `transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;`

#### Edit: I can see your code `transition: opacity .2s ease;` so you want to change this to:

`transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;`

Answer (score 0):

You need a little Javascript

1. When the [mouseenter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseenter.asp) add class (fade in)
2. When the [mouseleave](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseleave.asp)  add class (fade out)

or only CSS
[What is the opposite of :hover (on mouse leave)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995165/what-is-the-opposite-of-hover-on-mouse-leave)