# My code works when hovering in but not when hovering out

Tags: html, css

```
Alright, so when I use this code and hover over the object, the transition works. But if I take my mouse OFF of the object, the transition doesn't happen. I've seen other posts talk about this but the solutions don't work.
```

Here's my code in CSS:

```html
.square{
margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background:#3d3434;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.square:hover{
    outline: 3px solid #21ff46;
}
```

Also, I'm relatively new to coding and CSS.

Comment: Try adding the transition to the .square :hover as well

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995165/what-is-the-opposite-of-hover-on-mouse-leave

Comment: I tried adding it to the hover - didn't work and neither did the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works properly. The reason why you see no animation on mouseleave is that after hover pseudostate ends, there's no outline at all, and browser doesn't know to what position he has to shrink the outline. Also it doesn't understand what color it should preserve while shrinking, without hover state there's no color defined.

So, the solution is to add this line to your .square

```
outline: 0 solid #21ff46;
```

Leave the rest as it is, your problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks, but the transition is really choppy. How do i fix that now?

Comment: just play with numbers of transition duration, 0.25 is probably too low

also it's not the case here, of course, but try to experiment with 

.square {
will-change: outline;
}

If this improves the smoothness, then it means your PC is just not strong enough to handle that transition in regular mode, it hangs

Comment: I tried increasing it to .5 seconds. It's still really choppy